# How to indicate an Icelandic accent in writing?

Tags: accent

I have characters who natively speak Icelandic* and at least one of whom speaks English with an Icelandic accent.

I would like to indicate when they are speaking with that accent in writing, even if they're using English words.

I even found a few [YouTube videos](https://youtu.be/dveX8H1RaPM) about effecting the accent, but I don't know how to translate that into writing.

I'm already peppering the dialogue with Icelandic words, but sometimes that doesn't fit with the dialogue. I'm happy figuring out when to use it myself, but knowing how is a different matter!

* The words I'm using are from Icelandic, but in-fiction it's technically Dwarvish, but I am assuming the same accent.

Answer (score 1):

### Just Describe It

The first time your Dwarves speak, mention that it sounds [describe what you think Icelandic sounds like]. Pick some words that you think sound distinct, and mention the odd pronunciation sometimes when the characters use those words.

### Use it to Emphasize the Foreignness

The point of the accent is to highlight that they are foriegn, right? So be sure to mention it when cultures clash. If the Dwarves have a solution to a problem that violates local norms, that's the time to mention that the other characters really notice the accent.

It should really drive home the idea of the other characters staring at them like "**What kind of creature are you?**"

### Language Learning is Hard

Particularly for someone who learned a foreign language as an adult, reaching native level fluency can be very difficult. Your Dwarves should use a more basic vocabulary, use simpler sentence structures, and should search for words the right words more often. Have the Dwarf with the best English correct the other Dwarves. Have them converse in Dwarvish for a minute to figure out how to say what they want in English.

This way its not just flavor — you're learning things like which Dwarf put the most effort into learning English, which Dwarf they defer to when their in "Dwarvish mode" and who is first to get frustrated when they can't express themselves. Meaning: you're fleshing out the characters.